# Why put javascript:'' as iframe src?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I was browsing trough skydrive and trying to understand context menu build, and I stumbled uppon this code which was before `ul` of options:

```
<iframe 
       frameborder="no" 
       src="javascript:''" 
       scrolling="no" 
       style="position: absolute; 
              visibility: visible; 
              width: 186px; 
              height: 350px; 
              left: 0px; 
              top: 0px; 
              display: block;">
</iframe>
```

And I didn't understand why they added `<iframe>` with `src="javascript:''"` ?

Is it meant to fix x-domain request/functions calls?

Comment: If i had to guess it most likely because the SRC isnt known when the response is generated on the server and is later populated by JS. Using that just gives it a valid non-functioning src.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's there as a placeholder, ready for the server to insert code using AJAX or other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

definitions:

- An  tag is used to embed other documents within the main HTML document.
- The src attribute is used to define the location of the embedded document.

you example explained:

So for you example, they are inserting a JavaScript document in a certain area of the HTML document. Notice that they are not writing their JavaScript directly in the HTML document. It is a link to an outside source. This is helpful for team collaboration at places like Microsoft because they have people manage different files like CSS, JavaScript, and HTML.